# Android client set input message to textview

Tags: android, sockets, client

I am new to android and java programming and I am trying to program a server client connection.

The server runs without problems on my pc and the client runs on my android smartphone.

I can send a message from my phone to my server, but I can't send a message from the server to my client.

When I send this message the client crushes and closes itself.

I found a similar client on [this site](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.de/2012/07/android-tcp-connection-tutorial.html) and changed the listView of this client to a textView. After this change my problem occurred. I really hope that someone can help me with my problem.

Here is my Activity:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

public static final String MY_LOCAL_BROADCAST = "myLocalBroadCast";
public static final String KEY_RESPONSE = "key_response";
public static final String KEY_FIRSTRUN = "first_run";

Button btn;
EditText textOut;
TextView textIn;
TextView problems;
Button send;
private TCPClient myTcpClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textIn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
    send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);

    new ConnectTask(this.getApplicationContext()).execute("");

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String message = editText.getText().toString();

            //sends the message to the server
            if (myTcpClient != null) {
                myTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
            }
        }
    });
    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
        new ConnectTask(this.getApplicationContext()).execute("");
    }
    }

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean(KEY_FIRSTRUN, false);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(MY_LOCAL_BROADCAST));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String responseData = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_RESPONSE);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, responseData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {


    private Context context;

         public ConnectTask(Context context) {
             this.context = context;
         }

    @Override
    protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

        //we create a TCPClient object and
        myTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {

            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        myTcpClient.run();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.MY_LOCAL_BROADCAST);
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_RESPONSE, values);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
        textIn.setText(values[0]);
    }
}
}
```

and here is my TCPClient class:

```
package com.example.sercerclient2zweidreidrei;

import android.util.Log;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;


public class TCPClient {

private String serverMessage;
public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.2.107"; //your computer IP address
public static final int SERVERPORT = 4444;
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
private boolean mRun = false;

PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;

/**
 * constructor of the class. OnMessageReceived listens for the messages 
 * received from server
 */
public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Sends the message entered by client to the server
 * @param message text entered by client
 */
public void sendMessage(String message){
    if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
    }
}

public void stopClient() {
    mRun = false;
}

public void run() {
    mRun = true;

    try {
        // here you must put your computer's IP address.
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        try {
            //send the message to the server
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");
            Log.e("TCP Client", "C:Done.");

            //receive the message which the server sends back
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            //in this while the client listens for the messages send by the server
            while (mRun) {
                serverMessage = in.readLine();

                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                }
                serverMessage = null;
            }

            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

        } finally {
            //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
            //after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
            socket.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TCP", "C:Error", e);
    }
}

/*
 * Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message must be
 * implemented in the MyActivity class at on asynckTask doInBackground
 */
public interface OnMessageReceived {
    public void messageReceived(String message);
}
}
```

Finally here you can see my main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MyActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/Textausgabe" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/send_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="@string/Senden" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/EinkommenderText"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

and my LogCat:

> E/TCP Client(548): C: Connecting...
>
> E/TCP Client(548): C: Sent.
>
> E/TCP Client(548): C:Done.
>
> D/AndroidRuntime(548): Shutting down VM
>
> : W/dalvikvm(548): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception 
>   (group=0x409c01f8)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(548): java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(548):at com.example.sercerclient2zweidreidrei.MyActivity$connectTask.onProgressUpdate(MyActivity.java:72)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(548):    at 
>   com.example.sercerclient2zweidreidrei.MyActivity$connectTask.onProgressUpdate(MyActivity.java:1)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(548):    at 
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:618)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(548):    at 
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

Comment: Can you check whether the textIn is null in the onProgressUpdate() function? This code is a bit dangerous, because if you rotate the screen, the Activity will be re-created and the AsyncTask will be called again and will create a new TCPClient, without closing the previous one.

Comment: Can you eventually tell me a solution for your discribed problem? I already recognized that there is a problem when I rotate the screen. When I rotate the screen the connection crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A null pointer occured because your `TextView` etc isn't initialized properly.

You declare them globally but initialize new local variables that aren't linked to the global. Hence the global values are still null.

Changed `MyActivity` will be

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

      Button btn;
      EditText textOut;
      TextView textIn;
      TextView problems;
      Button send;
      private TCPClient myTcpClient;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);  
         editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
         textIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textin);
         send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);

        // connect to the server
        new connectTask().execute("");

send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String message = editText.getText().toString();

        //sends the message to the server
        if (myTcpClient != null) {
            myTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Do you also have an solution for what a have to change that the connection didn't crash if I rotate the screen? This is unfortunately my next problem i have. :(

Comment: There are several ways to handle this and its a common problem. Too tired to go into detail on it but I suggest you read http://www.fattybeagle.com/2011/02/14/android-asynctasks-during-a-screen-rotation-part-i/

Comment: Also if you want your question truly answered I suggest you just tick an answer here and start a new thread

Answer (score 0):

To avoid screen rotating issue, you have to create lazy bound between your Activity and your AsyncTask. For example your AsyncTask can send the response to your Activity via LocalBroadcastReceiver. Besides you should also consider using a Service instead of AsyncTask.

A draft LocalBroadcastReceiver example.

An Activity that starts an AsyncTask and displays the LocalBroadcast result (as Intent data) in a Toast (do not forget to unregister from this Broadcast, e.g. in *onPause(...)* as in this example):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String MY_LOCAL_BROADCAST = "myLocalBroadCast";
    public static final String KEY_RESPONSE = "key_response";
    public static final String KEY_FIRSTRUN = "first_run";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState!=null && savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_FIRSTRUN,true)) {
          new ConnectTask(this.getApplicationContext()).execute("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_FIRSTRUN, false);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(MY_LOCAL_BROADCAST));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String responseData = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_RESPONSE);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, responseData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
}
```

An *AsyncTask* that sends *LocalBroadCast* when the *AsyncTask* finishes. You can also send *LocalBoradcast* similarly in your *onProgressUpdate(...)*:

```
public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Context context;

    public ConnectTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.MY_LOCAL_BROADCAST);
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_RESPONSE, result);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my source code and edited also my source code here, but there are already some mistakes and i don't know how to solve them. Can you please say me what i have to change. If a have to write a service this would be a really big problem for me, because i have no idea how this works.

Comment: Hello, put the LocalBroadcast sending code to onProgressUpdate() from onPostExecute().
Besides do not forget to unregister from LoaclBroadcast in your Activity's onPause() as in the example above.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are always two mistakes remaining on  'void' in the lines 'protected void onResume() {' and 'protected void onPause() {'. Besides there are problems with putting the code from onPostExecute() to onUpdate() with the parametes. There is shows that 'context' and 'result' cannot be resolved to a variable. :(

Comment: You should get the context parameter in the Constructor of your AsyncTask. See the edited code above. Besides you should use your values[0] instead of result in progressUpdate() as it stores your String value.

Comment: I don't want to annoy you, but there are still the mistakes on 'void' and i don't know how to solve them, unfortunately.

Comment: No problem:) What are the problems, what does Eclipse say? Try to remove @Override from the functions or set your source level to Java 1.6.

Comment: Eclipse says: Multiple markers at this line   - Syntax error, insert"enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName     - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement      - Syntax error on token "void", @expected        This is said at both voids and removing Override made no difference.

Comment: I've created a new MainActivity with the code above and no errors. Maybe there is an error somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Now i know where the problem with the void mistake was. The problem didn't occur when you close 'public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {' before '@Override public void onResume(){' and so on. I closed this after the hole 'private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {'. But very unfortunately there is still the problem that the connection get lost when i swith the screen. :( :( :( You don't know another solution, do you?

Comment: You can save in the Activity's onSavedInstanceState(...) function whether it has been exited e.g. because of screen rotation. The outState Bundle here will be passed to the Activity's onCreate(..) when it starts next time. I've modified the code, please check it. This way your AsyncTask should be called only once.

Comment: You are missing the onSavedInstanceState() function from your Activity and you have tow new connectTask().execute(""); line in your onCreate() function in your Activity code. Put this execute witht the if statement at the end of onCreate().

Comment: So know I edited my source Code and the source code here, but it is still doesn't work after switching the screen.

Comment: If i start my app with this source code i am also unable to send a message without switching to screen. When i delete the if-loop with '(savedInstanceState==null) {' it works.

Comment: Hello, try change the if statement to this: if (savedInstanceState!=null && savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_FIRSTRUN,true)) {...

Comment: I really don't like to say this, but it doesn't work. I can send a message, but the connection crashes when I switch the screen. :(

Comment: In your code there is a textIn.setText(values[0]); line. Are your Activiy and AsyncTask in different java files? Please put them in different files! Besides you should put this textIn.setText(values[0]); line when you receive the LocalBroadCast in your Activity. E.g. after the Toast.makeText(...)... line.

Comment: When I try to put this textIn.setText(values[0]); line after Toast.makeText(...) line then there is missing a parameter or do i have to create there again a parameter?

Comment: After putting the activity and the asynctask into different files i am unable to send a message. I also changed textIn.setText(values [0]); into textIn.setText(responseData); was this correct?

Comment: Yes, that should be correct. Try to put breakpoints in the code and do some debug to see what is wrong.

Comment: Please look in google how to debug a Java/Android project in Eclipse.

Comment: Ok. I will look up for this

Comment: Okay. Guys I'll just add to this crazy thread. When you'll have long conversations try having them on chat. Also other developers may look at this question in the future and see a completely unrelated answer @Lukas. If you have a new problem ask a new question. This isn't only a forum but also a reference for the future. Try to keep it clean